# Как сделать, чтобы высота textarea уменьшалась при удалении текста?

Tags: javascript, html

Я сделал код, который расширяет нижнюю границу при добавлении текста:

```
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  if(this.scrollTop > 0){
    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
});
```

Но обратное сделать не получается.

Comment: на хабре статья есть. https://habr.com/ru/post/114182/, по такому принципу многие делают. У тех же trelo почти также текстовые поля для блоков реализованы.

Answer (score 0):

"keyup" не отработает, если вы с помощью контекстного меню (правой кнопкой мыши) вставите, скажем, текст в свой texatrea. Думаю, лучше подойдет event "input"

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const textarea = document.querySelector('#someArea');

    //Каждые 30 символов будем увеличивать\уменьшать высоту с шагом 20px
    const heightStep = 20, heightPerSymbols = 30;

    textarea.addEventListener('input', event => 
        event.currentTarget.style.height = (Math.ceil(event.currentTarget.value.length / heightPerSymbols) * heightStep) + 'px'
    );
})
```